# '<' not supported between cases - Number guessing game

Tags: python

I am trying to create a number guessing game in Python for a school project. I have made a basic game that will work fairly well, but I want to add in some exception handling in case the user enters something incorrectly. For example, this is a section of my code:

```
def Normal_Guess():
    number = round(random.uniform(0.0, 100.0),2)
    guess = ""
    while guess != number:
        try:
            guess = float(input("Please guess a number between 0 and 100: "))
        except ValueError or TypeError:
            print ("That isn't even a number!")

        if guess < number and guess >= 0:
            print ("You need to guess higher!")
        elif guess > number and guess <= 100:
            print ("You need to guess lower!")
        elif guess == number:
            print("Congratulations! You guessed the number!")
        elif guess < 0 or guess > 100: 
            print ("The number you guessed is not between 0 and 100")
        else: 
            print("That isn't even a number!")
    New_Game()
```

This works fine when the user enters a float or integer value as "guess", and the Try-Except clause I have seems to catch if the user enters anything but a number at first, but the program seems to also carry on to the "if" statements. I am getting a TypeError saying that "'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'".

I have tried encompassing the entire loop in a Try-Except clause, and that doesn't work. I have no clue what I am doing wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: within your `except` loop, use `continue` after printing the message.

Comment: Alternatively, add an `else` clause to your `try`-`except` block to handle the case where there is no exception explicitly.

Comment: Alternatively, move your `if else` chain *inside* the `try` block, since that's where it logically belongs.

Comment: Or just get rid of the except block and make your first if into `if guess == '':`

Comment: `except ValueError or TypeError` isn't how you catch either of two types of error. That needs to be `except (ValueError, TypeError)`. (The parentheses are mandatory.)

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your error - you code works fine.

Comment: @MarianD. Try typing in some non-integer value...

Comment: As a side note here, python allows [Chained Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons). That means that your `if guess < number and guess >= 0:` can be simplified to `if 0 <= guess < number:`. I haven't run the tests myself but the linked text seems to point to the simplified version possibly being better in terms of performance and, IMHO, much more readable.

Comment: @EricEdLohmar. It is not likely to have better performance since I am pretty sure it expands out to the same sequence of steps.

Comment: @Mad Physicist the documentation says it performs the same but the middle value, `guess` in this case, is only evaluated once. My logic was less evaluation == more performant code.

Comment: @EricEdLohmar. You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, the way you are catching the exception is invalid. The value of the expression `ValueError or TypeError` is always just going to be `ValueError` because that is how short-circuiting works with two non-`False` arguments. To get both types of errors to trigger the block, use a `tuple`, like `(ValueError, TypeError)`.

The problem is that even if an exception is caught in your code, it will continue on to the `if` block. You have four simple options to avoid this:

1. Use a `continue` statement in the `except` block to tell the loop to move on without processing the following `if` structure:

   ```
   try:
       guess = float(input("Please guess a number between 0 and 100: "))
   except (ValueError, TypeError):
       print ("That isn't even a number!")
       continue
   ```

   This is probably the cleanest and easiest of the four options.
2. Do not use an `except` block to respond to the error. Instead, rely on the fact that the value of guess is still `""`. For this to work, you will have to pre-initialize `guess` with every iteration of the loop instead of once outside the loop:

   ```
   while guess != number:
       guess = ""
       try:
           guess = float(input("Please guess a number between 0 and 100: "))
       except (ValueError, TypeError):
           pass
       
       if guess == "":
           print ("That isn't even a number!")
       elif guess < number and guess >= 0:
           ...
   ```

   Personally, I am not a fan of this approach because it requires an initialization in every loop. This is not bad, just not as clean as option #1.

   A variation on this option is to check directly if `guess` is an instance of `str`. You can then initialize it to the user input, making the conversion operation cleaner:

   ```
   while guess != number:
       guess = input("Please guess a number between 0 and 100: ")
       try:
           guess = float(guess)
       except (ValueError, TypeError):
           pass
       
       if isinstance(guess, str):
           print ("That isn't even a number!")
       elif guess < number and guess >= 0:
           ...
   ```
3. Use the `else` clause that is one of the possible elements of a `try` block. This clause gets executed *only* if no exception occurred:

   ```
   try:
       guess = float(input("Please guess a number between 0 and 100: "))
   except (ValueError, TypeError):
       print ("That isn't even a number!")
   else:
       if guess < number and guess >= 0:
           ...
   ```

   While this option creates an added layer of indentation, it is a possibility worth keeping in mind for those cases where a plain `continue` won't work. This happens sometimes when you need to do additional processing for both error and non-error cases, before you branch.
4. Put the entire `if` block into the `try` block. This way it will only be executed if there is no error. This is my least favorite option because I like my `try` blocks to be as trimmed-down as possible to avoid catching exceptions I did not intend to. In Python, `try` is relatively less of a performance-killer than in a language like Java, so for your simple case, this is still an option:

   ```
   try:
       guess = float(input("Please guess a number between 0 and 100: "))
       if guess < number and guess >= 0:
           ...
   except (ValueError, TypeError):
       print ("That isn't even a number!")
   ```

Comment: 4: The problem with putting extra things in a try block is that you risk catching exceptions that you didn't mean to handle.

Comment: Thank you for the help! My code is working flawlessly now!

Comment: @Cubemaster. Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an else statement.

Your except catch print, but let script continue running.  It will continue to all of if statements even when the catch is hit. What you want to do is skip the main logic of your function when the except is hit. Use the **ELSE** clause of the try-catch-else-finally block.

```
import random

def Normal_Guess():
    number = round(random.uniform(0.0, 100.0),2)
    guess = ""
    while guess != number:
        try:
            guess = float(input("Please guess a number between 0 and 100: "))
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            print ("That isn't even a number!")
        else:
            if guess < number and guess >= 0:
                print ("You need to guess higher!")
            elif guess > number and guess <= 100:
                print ("You need to guess lower!")
            elif guess == number:
                print("Congratulations! You guessed the number!")
            elif guess < 0 or guess > 100:
                print ("The number you guessed is not between 0 and 100")
            else:
                print("That isn't even a number!")

Normal_Guess()
```

Comment: `except ValueError or TypeError:` needs to be `except (ValueError, TypeError):` as Mad Physicist points out in his answer.